How can I print a content in the middle of the screen in Rust?
Fisrtly I tried with a lot of libs and none of them seemed to work properly, i put the terminal width manually too and the text is all the same thing, it's not in the center of the terminal, does somebody what should I make?
OBS: I discovered, it's because of the colors, but how can i print it in the center and with colors? (without colors it goes right, thats how i discovered)
fn print_centered(content: &str) {
    let term_size = crossterm::terminal::size();
    let term_width = term_size.unwrap_or((80, 24)).0 as usize;

    println!("{: ^term_width$}", content);
}



I tried manually and with a lot of crates and didn't center the content properly as expected.

What is your issue: 1. the terminal size is not reported correctly; or 2. the text is not centered, despite correct size?

The terminal size is reported correctly as i checked it manually, but printing the text it isnt in the center as you can see in the image

If you're also printing ANSI color codes, those may shift the text around relative to the center if they're not symmetric around the text, as can multi-code-point unicode characters.

thats it, but how would i print it in the center with colors?

Hard to tell from an image, but the code seems very reasonable.
I would probably replace the space with some printable character like e.g.
println!("{:~^term_width$}", content); and then count.
How many characters are printed in total?  Does that match the output of tput cols?

it not matches the term_width because of colors i think

@mi66mc: I see, that makes sense. Rust's format string will give you term_width unicode characters, regardless of their displayed size. If you include ansi escape sequences in content (which are multiple characters, but not displayed), the displayed length will be too short. You could use a library like ansi parser to iterate through content and figure out the actual length of the text, or alternatively just figure out the length before adding the ansii escapes.

If you found an answer, please post it, after all collecting a bunch of QA pairs is the entire point of [so].

The solution have overall been hinted at in the comments. So this is the culmination of that, along with an actual solution.
As you already figured out, the issue is that the standard fill/alignment formatting, is based on characters. While embedding ANSI color codes into a string is thus counted as characters.
This is observable using the following code:
let width = 25;
let text = "Hello World";
let text2 = format!("\x1b[94m{}\x1b[39m", text);

println!("{:-^width$}", "");
println!("{:-^width$}", text);
println!("{:-^width$}", text2);

println!();
println!("{} characters", text.chars().count());
println!("{} characters", text2.chars().count());

Which outputs:

Using an image, since the output is colored.

An easy workaround, is to use the console crate, which provides various utilities for measuring text, padding, truncating etc. While accounting for ANSI codes:

measure_text_width()
pad_str()
strip_ansi_codes()
truncate_str()
AnsiCodeIterator

You can even use Term.size() to get the terminal width.
To center a string containing ANSI codes, then you'd specifically use pad_str():
use console::{pad_str, Alignment};

let width = 25;
let text = "Hello World";
let text2 = format!("\x1b[94m{}\x1b[39m", text);

let text = pad_str(text, width, Alignment::Center, None);
let text2 = pad_str(&text2, width, Alignment::Center, None);

println!("{:-^width$}", "");
println!("{text}");
println!("{text2}");
println!("{:-^width$}", "");

Which outputs:


Again, pad_str() does not break text, even if it is truncated. For instance, let's set the width to 6 and use … (ellipsis) for truncation.
use console::{pad_str, Alignment};

const ELLIPSIS: &str = "\u{2026}";

let width = 6;
let text = "Hello World";
let text2 = format!("\x1b[94m{}\x1b[39m", text);

let text = pad_str(text, width, Alignment::Center, Some(ELLIPSIS));
let text2 = pad_str(&text2, width, Alignment::Center, Some(ELLIPSIS));

println!("{:-^width$}", "");
println!("{text}");
println!("{text2}");
println!("{:-^width$}", "");

Which correctly outputs:

